# TOP 5 JOGADORES

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou tento problemas no meu codigo, eu queria que ele pegasse os 5 melhores jogadores que mais adquiriram produtos no mês, o problema é que eu queria que ele pegasse o user do cara e mostrasse o valor que ele pagou, caso ele tivesse mais compras, ele ia apenas somar o valor.

eu tentei :

```php
    public function topShopping()
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `website_transactions` ORDER BY `transaction_AMOUNT` DESC LIMIT 5");
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 0) { return "<div class=\"col-md-12\">
            <div class=\"compra\" onclick=\"\">
            <img class=\"imgboder\" src=\"https://minotar.net/avatar/steve/60\">
            <p><b>NENHUMA COMPRA REGISTRADA</b></p>
        </div>
            </div>"; }
        $fetch = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $return = "";
        foreach ($fetch as $key => $rs)
        {

            $posicao = $key + 1;
            $name = $rs->transaction_USERNAME;
            $valor = $rs->transaction_AMOUNT;
            $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $rs->transaction_DATE)->format('Y/m/d');
            $return .= "<b>
            <tr class=\"tr\" style=\"border-radius: 10px;white-space: nowrap;\">
                <td class=\"th\">$posicao</td>
                <td class=\"th\"><img style=\"vertical-align: sub;width:20px!important;height:20px!important;border-radius: 3px;\" src=\"https://minotar.net/avatar/$name/100\"> $name <i class=\"fas fa-crown\"></i></td>
                <td class=\"th\">R$ $valor</td>
            </tr></b>";

    }
        return "{$return}";
    }
```

mas o resultado é [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

queria saber se eu consigo colocar para somar o valor depois de varias compras com o mesmo user

meu mysql: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer isso você precisa somar o transaction_amount do período que você quer, agrupar os resultados por usuário e ordenar por ordem decrescente de valor. Aqui tem um exemplo de como fazer isso, a consulta soma o valor comprado e também conta o total de transações do usuário:

```
select transaction_USERNAME, sum(transaction_AMOUNT) as total_amount, count(transaction_CODE) as 
total_transactions from website_transactions
WHERE MONTH(transaction_DATE) = 8 AND YEAR(transaction_DATE) = 2019
GROUP BY transaction_USERNAME
ORDER BY sum(transaction_amount) DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: não funcinou
deu erro: http://prntscr.com/ozup1h

Comment: Arrumei o nome da coluna no agrupamento e editei a resposta

Comment: vlw irmão, consegui aqui